# Macro Loop with Dynamic Range

Tags: function, excel, offset, vba

I'm trying to automate the following process using a Excel but I'm experiencing some difficulties as obviously I need to set up a variable within the OFFSET function:

```
Sheets("XXX").Visible = True
Sheets("XXX").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="XXX_aaa", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=OFFSET('XXX'!R2C1,0,1,COUNTA('XXX'!C1),21)"
Sheets("XXX").Visible = False

Sheets("YYY").Visible = True
Sheets("YYY").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="YYY_bbb", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=OFFSET('YYY'!R2C1,0,1,COUNTA('YYY'!C1),21)"
Sheets("YYY").Visible = False

Sheets("ZZZ").Visible = True
Sheets("ZZZ").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ZZZ_ccc", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=OFFSET('ZZZ'!R2C1,0,1,COUNTA('ZZZ'!C1),21)"
Sheets("ZZZ").Visible = False`
```

Is there an easy macro function I can use to automate this task (it has to be repeated 30 times !)

Thanks !

Comment: Repeat 30 times is that how many sheets you have? Can you give us the Sheet Index you want to repeat it for? Sheets 1:30? or 2:31 for example? You have to at least have 1 sheet always visible also

Comment: Hi Yes I have a Control Sheet. It has to be repeated for Sheets 2 to 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on a ***COPY*** of the workbook you are working with:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim intCurrentSheet As Integer
Dim lngLastRow As Long

For intCurrentSheet = 2 To 31

    lngLastRow = Sheets(intCurrentSheet).Range("U1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets(intCurrentSheet).Range("A2:U" & lngLastRow).Name = Sheets(intCurrentSheet).Name & _
                                                           "_" & Chr(intCurrentSheet + 63) & _
                                                           Chr(intCurrentSheet + 63) & _
                                                           Chr(intCurrentSheet + 63)
    Sheets(intCurrentSheet).Visible = False

Next intCurrentSheet

End Sub
```